# Mean stack: Bcrypt is not hashing my password

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, encryption, mean-stack

The connection is working correctly, i'm able to etc post a new user, edit them. Now I want to use bcrypt to "crypt" the password in my mongoDB. What am I doing wrong?

In my app.js file

I do have " var bcrypt = require('bcrypt'); " I also ref mongoose, express and everything as it should

Code:

```
app.post('/api/user', (req, res) => {

    res.redirect('http://localhost:4200/');

    var newUserData = { username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password, mail: req.body.mail, role: "user" };

    const saltRounds = 10;
    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(newUserData.req.body.password, saltRounds);

    bcrypt.compareSync(newUserData.req.body.password, hash);


    var user = new User(newUserData, function(err) {
    });

    user.save();
});
```

Comment: How can you do `newUserData.req.body.password`? `newUserData` doesn't seem to have a key `req`

Comment: I don't know I'm just trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to assign the newly generated `hash` to that user's password. It doesn't do that automatically for you.

You should do something like this after you have obtaind the `hash` and before you create the User object.

```js
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(newUserData.password, saltRounds);

newUserData.password = hash;
```

Also, calling `bcrypt.compareSync` here like that is meaningless and you should probably go with the async version in case of hashing because the operation is quite expensive and you do not want to block your main thread by it.

Comment: Hm what do you mean? How would I do that

Comment: Thanks! You solved it! Smart thinking, perhaps this was a dumb question of me, but everyone learns at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This should do your job:

```
app.post('/api/user', (req, res) => {

    res.redirect('http://localhost:4200/');

    const saltRounds = 10;
    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, saltRounds);

    var newUserData = { username: req.body.username, password: hash, mail: req.body.mail, role: "user" };


    var user = new User(newUserData, function(err) {
    });

    user.save();
    });
```

A better (recommended) way is to do it asynchronously:

```
bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    var newUserData = { username: req.body.username, password: hash, mail: req.body.mail, role: "user" };


    var user = new User(newUserData, function(err) {
    });

    user.save();
    });
});
```